# Conda is broken

Tags: python, conda

I am having a really annoying problem. Conda seems to be broken on Mac and I am getting a permission denied to uninstall and install. Not a huge deal since I am using conda in ec2 most of the time, but I am hoping to learn what the problem is. If I run a simple code such as "conda update conda" from command I am getting the error below. "conda --version" gives me 4.11

```
conda update conda 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1080, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 84, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 81, in do_call
    module = import_module(relative_mod, __name__.rsplit('.', 1)[0])
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/main_update.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .install import install
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ..core.index import calculate_channel_urls, get_index
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/package_cache_data.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .path_actions import CacheUrlAction, ExtractPackageAction
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/path_actions.py", line 30, in <module>
    from ..gateways.connection.download import download
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/gateways/connection/download.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .session import CondaSession
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/gateways/connection/session.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .adapters.s3 import S3Adapter
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/gateways/connection/adapters/s3.py", line 14, in <module>
    boto3.client('s3')  # https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8993
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 93, in client
    return _get_default_session().client(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 258, in client
    return self._session.create_client(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 847, in create_client
    client = client_creator.create_client(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 86, in create_client
    client_args = self._get_client_args(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 355, in _get_client_args
    return args_creator.get_client_args(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/args.py", line 99, in get_client_args
    endpoint = endpoint_creator.create_endpoint(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 287, in create_endpoint
    raise ValueError("Invalid endpoint: %s" % endpoint_url)
ValueError: Invalid endpoint: https://s3..amazonaws.com

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda", line 13, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 152, in main
    return conda_exception_handler(_main, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1372, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = exception_handler(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1083, in __call__
    return self.handle_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1127, in handle_exception
    return self.handle_unexpected_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1138, in handle_unexpected_exception
    self.print_unexpected_error_report(error_report)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1208, in print_unexpected_error_report
    from .cli.main_info import get_env_vars_str, get_main_info_str
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/cli/main_info.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ..core.index import _supplement_index_with_system
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/package_cache_data.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .path_actions import CacheUrlAction, ExtractPackageAction
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/core/path_actions.py", line 30, in <module>
    from ..gateways.connection.download import download
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/gateways/connection/download.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .session import CondaSession
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/gateways/connection/session.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .adapters.s3 import S3Adapter
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/gateways/connection/adapters/s3.py", line 14, in <module>
    boto3.client('s3')  # https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8993
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 93, in client
    return _get_default_session().client(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 258, in client
    return self._session.create_client(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 847, in create_client
    client = client_creator.create_client(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 86, in create_client
    client_args = self._get_client_args(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 355, in _get_client_args
    return args_creator.get_client_args(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/args.py", line 99, in get_client_args
    endpoint = endpoint_creator.create_endpoint(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 287, in create_endpoint
    raise ValueError("Invalid endpoint: %s" % endpoint_url)
ValueError: Invalid endpoint: https://s3..amazonaws.com
```

Comment: Whenever you think something that's used on a daily basis by millions of users is "broken" and nobody seems to notice, you can be pretty confident you're actually just making a mistake, or have made mistakes when installing or configuring your tools. Check your `~/.aws/credentials` or `~/.aws/config` files

Comment: `https://s3..amazonaws.com` as mentioned in the error message is clearly invalid.  Open up the source files mentioned in the stack trace and find out where it came from.    Start with `botocore/endpoint.py` and go up from there.  Or just reinstall the latest version of Conda from scratch.

Comment: Did you recently update something in the **base** environment? The Conda v4.11 is very recent. Did the `boto3` also change versions?  Note that [`micromamba`](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#micromamba) provides standalone functionality for manipulating Conda environments, which is useful for fixing borken **base** environments (e.g., rollback a revision).